# How to use an object from another TS file (knockout.js)

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I need to use an object from another TS file, for example I have a API response ine one.ts and I need to use that in two.ts

i tried exporting and importing elements but to no avail

this snippet is in my one.ts

```
getDealStatusInfo(dealid) {
            var statusRes
            DealApiControllers.GetDealStatus(dealid,
                (response) => {
                    statusRes = response;
                    console.log(statusRes)
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });

        }
```

I need to use the statusRes object in two.ts

Answer (score 0):

Exported variable should be out of function scope

One.ts

```
export var statusRes ;
getDealStatusInfo(dealid) {
            DealApiControllers.GetDealStatus(dealid,
                (response) => {
                    statusRes = response;
                    console.log(statusRes)
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });

        }
```

Two.ts

```
import statusRes from './one'
```

but You have to wait for statusRes to be retrieved from the server.

You can use observable design pattern to subscribe on variable changes.

For observable design pattern you can use RXJS lib or you have to implement it.

Or you can export the function which will handle the response from two.ts and import it into one.ts then call that function once you get the response.

one.ts

```
import handleRes from './two'
getDealStatusInfo(dealid) {
            var statusRes
            DealApiControllers.GetDealStatus(dealid,
                (response) => {
                    statusRes = response;
                    handleRes(statusRes);
                    console.log(statusRes);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });

        }
```

two.ts

```
export function handleRes(statusRes){
  // do stuff
  console.log(statusRes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably in your best interest to refactor the function to return a promise that resolves the value you are trying to retrieve

```
export function getDealStatusInfo(dealid) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    DealApiControllers.GetDealStatus(
      dealid,
      (response) => resolve(response),
      (error) => reject(error)
  })
}
```

Then from the consuming side, use `.then` or `async`/`await`...

```
import { getDealStatusInfo } from './two'

getDealStatusInfo().then((response) => { /* do work*/ })
```

---

If something else is responsible for calling `getDealStatusInfo`, you can instead export an observable from the top level which `getDealStatusInfo` updates, and subscribe to changes.

```
export const statusResponse = ko.observable()

function getDealStatusInfo(dealId) {
  DealApiControllers.GetDealStatus(
    dealId,
    (res) => statusResponse(res),
    (err) => console.error(err)
  )
}
```

```
import { statusResponse } from './two'

statusResponse() // current value

statusResponse.subscribe((res) => {
  // handle update
})
```